# What information should I be logging in my web app?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, logging, instrumentation

I finishing up a web application and I'm trying to implement some logging. I've never seen any good examples of what to log. Is it just exceptions? Are there other things I should be logging? What type of information do you find useful for finding and fixing bugs.

Looking for some specific guidance and best practices.

Thanks

**Follow up**

If I'm logging exceptions what information specifically should I be logging? Should I be doing something more than `_log.Error(ex.Message, ex);` ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here is my logical breakdown of what can be logged within and application, why you might want to and how you might go about doing it. No matter what I would recommend using a logging framework such as log4net when implementing.

### Exception Logging

When everything else has failed, this should not. It is a good idea to have a central means of capturing all unhanded exceptions. This shouldn't 
be much harder then wrapping your entire application in a giant try/catch unless you are using more than on thread. The work doesn't end here 
though because if you wait until the exception reaches you a lot of useful information would have gone out of scope. At the very least you should 
try to collect specific pieces of the application state that are likely to help with debugging as the stack unwinds. Your application should always be prepared to produce this type of log output, especially in production. Make sure to take a look at [ELMAH](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/) if you haven't already. I haven't tried it but I have [heard great things](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ELMAHErrorLoggingModulesAndHandlersForASPNETAndMVCToo.aspx)

### Application Logging

What I call application logs includes any log that captures information about what your application is doing on a conceptual level such as "Deleted Order" or "A User Signed On". This kind of information can be useful in analyzing trends, auditing the system, locking it down, testing, security and detecting bugs of coarse. It is probably a good idea to plan on leaving these logs on in production as well, perhaps at variable levels of granularity.

### Trace Logging

Trace logging, to me, represents the most granular form of logging. At this level you focus less on what the application is doing and more on how it is doing it. This is one step above actually walking through the code line by line. It is probably most helpful in dealing with concurrency issues or anything for that matter which is hard to reproduce. You wouldn't want to always have this running, probably only turning it on when needed.

Lastly, as with so many other things that usually only get addressed at the very end, the best time to think about logging is at the beginning of a project so that the application can be designed with it in mind. Great question though!

Comment: Wouldn't it be more helpful to log `User xyz Signed On` instead of `A User Signed On`? (Great answer, thanks).

Answer (score 8):

Some things to log:

- business actions, such as adding/deleting items. Talk to your app's business owner to come up with a list of things that are useful. These should make sense to the business, not to you (for example: when user submitted report, when user creates a new process, etc)
- exceptions
- exceptions
- exceptions

Some things to NOT to log:

- do not log information simply for tracking user usage. Use an analytics tool for that (which tracks the client in javascirpt, not in the client)
- do not track passwords or hashes of passwords (huge security issue)

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you should log page/resource accesses which are not yet defined in your application, but are requested by clients. That way, you may be able to find vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 4):

It depends on the application and its audience. If you are managing sales or trading stocks, you probably should log more info than say a personal blog. When you need the log most is when  an error is happening in your production environment, but can't reproduce it locally. Having log level and log hierarchy would help in such situations, because you can dynamically increase the log level. See [log4j's documentation](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html) and [log4net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/index.html).

Answer (score 4):

My few cents.
Besides using log severity and exceptions properly, consider structuring your log statements so that you could easily look though the log data in the future. For example - extracting meaningful info quickly, doing queries etc. There is no problem to generate an ocean of log data, the problem is to convert this data into information. So, structuring and defining it beforehand helps in later usage. If you use log4j, I would also suggest using mapped diagnostic context (MDC) - this helps a lot for tracking session contexts. Aside from trace and info, I would also use debug level where I usually keep temp. items. Those could be filtered out or disabled when not needed.

Answer (score 3):

You probably shouldn't be thinking of this at this stage, rather, logging is helpful to consider at every stage of development to help diffuse potential bugs before they arise.  Depending on your program, I would try to capture as much information as possible.  Log everything.  You can always stop logging certain components or processes if you don't reference that data enough.  There is no such thing as too much information.

From my (limited) experience, if you don't want to make a specific error table for each possible error type, construct a generic database table that accepts general information as well as a string that you can populate with exception data, confirmation messages during successful yet important processes, etc.  I've used a generic function with parameters for this.

You should also consider the ability to turn logging off if necessary.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

I beleive when you log an exception you should also save current date and time, requested url, url refferer and user IP address.