# Alternatives to Console.Writeline() for printing debug information from a console application?

Tags: c#, .net, debugging, testing, console-application

I have a C# console application. It is gathering info from several data sources and centralising them in another. Occasionally, it hits some bugs - connection strings stop working; schemas change etc.

At the moment, I am simply printing out debug information using `Console.WriteLine();` - this is obviously an awful idea...not least because the application is a scheduled task running every night, so I never see this debug information anyway!

What should I do to allow for simple debugging when the program fails? What is my best practice in this case ?

Thanks very much.

Comment: Write the informatin to a log file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a logging library.  [log4net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/) seems to be the most popular choice.

Answer (score 3):

Use `Debug.WriteLine()`. It'll print to the assigned listeners (default only your Visual Studio Output window, but you can hook it up to the Console). If this is for troubleshooting production issues, I'd strongly advise to implement logging in your application.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [System.Diagnostics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.aspx).  [Debug class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debug) is a better choice than `Console`, for starters.

`log4net` (as linked by @Tim S.) is a useful framework for general diagnostics output, at different levels of severity.

Answer (score 1):

You should read about different [logging/error strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/566358/error-handling-logging-strategy).

I suggest that you start off by using a library like [log4net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/) where you can define what kind of format you want for your logs.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using the `EventLog` class to write to the application event log (or your own custom log).  You could alternatively write to a custom log file of your own choosing.  The event log, however has the advantage of easily being viewable remotely from any machine.  In addition, if this application is truly unattended, you could have it send an email notification when it fails to the system administrator.

Answer (score 0):

You want a logging framework, such as [log4net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/) or the [Enterprise Library Logging Block](http://entlib.codeplex.com/). These frameworks will allow you to log to a database, log file, or the Event Log for later viewing and retrieval.